# Customizing Matplotlib Legend

Tags: python, numpy, graph, matplotlib, legend

Below I have a stacked bar chart with a legend. There are three "stacks" that comprise each bar: a, b, and c.

My legend currently has an entry for each stack, `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'`. I want to add an additional legend entry that has shows blue + green = 'combination of a + b', in the same legend (or nearby). Does that make sense? So my new legend should have 4 entries. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

My picture:
[image]

My code:

```
#graph specifications
d_widths = [(source2['grant'][i]/total)[0] for i in range(8)]
d_colors = ['r','g','b']
d_labels = ('<25000', '25000-\n50000', '50000-\n75000', '75000-\n100000', '100000-\n150000', '150000-\n200000', '200000-\n250000', '250000-\n300000')
d = np.array([[source[k][i] for k in ('grant', 'stud', 'par')] for i in range(8)])

#the graph
fig = plt.figure(facecolor='white')
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='white')
mygraph = StackedBarGrapher()
mygraph.stackedBarPlot(ax1,d,d_colors, edgeCols=['#000000']*3,widths = d_widths,  showFirst = 8, xLabels=d_labels,scale=True, axspacing=.3)

ax1.legend = plt.legend(('a', 'b', 'c'), loc='lower right', frameon=True)
frame = ax1.legend.get_frame()
frame.set_facecolor([1,1,1])
frame.set_alpha(.95)
```

Comment: see http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/legend_guide.html#legend-handler

Comment: Maybe just say it in your caption? It's implied in the nature of your graph that the sum of two sections represents the combination of two samples (by the way did you really mean `blue + green = 'combination of a + b'`, because `a` is red in your example).

Comment: Oh whoops I meant `green + blue = b + c`, sry about that. The first comment was interesting, however I couldn't figure out how to use it to get both the blue square and green square and a `+` sign in between. Yes I might just use a caption if there is no within python solution.